# `.find('li')` on `bs4.element.Tag` object gives None even though `<li>` tag exists inside soup

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse an url content with beautifulsoup after `requests.get()` [not showed in code]. The parser being used is `"html.parser"`. I have the following code snippet in a large script.

```
print(f"subheading : {subheading}")
print(f"type : {type(subheading)}")
print(f"dir : {dir(subheading)}")
if subheading.find('ul'):
    print(f"Going for next level subheading search")
else:
    c2 = subheading.find("li")
    print(f"c2 : {c2}")
```

The first print statement gives me this in stdout:

```
subheading : <li><a href="/handbook/PRIN/1/1.html?date=2022-10-14&amp;timeline=True">PRIN 1.1 Application and purpose</a></li>
```

I added a type check and the attribute list check, just to confirm whether I'm doing anything wrong. The second and third print statements gives me this :

```
type : <class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
dir : ['DEFAULT_INTERESTING_STRING_TYPES', '__bool__', '__call__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__copy__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__unicode__', '__weakref__', '_all_strings', '_find_all', '_find_one', '_is_xml', '_lastRecursiveChild', '_last_descendant', '_should_pretty_print', 'append', 'attrs', 'can_be_empty_element', 'cdata_list_attributes', 'childGenerator', 'children', 'clear', 'contents', 'decode', 'decode_contents', 'decompose', 'decomposed', 'default', 'descendants', 'encode', 'encode_contents', 'extend', 'extract', 'fetchNextSiblings', 'fetchParents', 'fetchPrevious', 'fetchPreviousSiblings', 'find', 'findAll', 'findAllNext', 'findAllPrevious', 'findChild', 'findChildren', 'findNext', 'findNextSibling', 'findNextSiblings', 'findParent', 'findParents', 'findPrevious', 'findPreviousSibling', 'findPreviousSiblings', 'find_all', 'find_all_next', 'find_all_previous', 'find_next', 'find_next_sibling', 'find_next_siblings', 'find_parent', 'find_parents', 'find_previous', 'find_previous_sibling', 'find_previous_siblings', 'format_string', 'formatter_for_name', 'get', 'getText', 'get_attribute_list', 'get_text', 'has_attr', 'has_key', 'hidden', 'index', 'insert', 'insert_after', 'insert_before', 'interesting_string_types', 'isSelfClosing', 'is_empty_element', 'known_xml', 'name', 'namespace', 'next', 'nextGenerator', 'nextSibling', 'nextSiblingGenerator', 'next_element', 'next_elements', 'next_sibling', 'next_siblings', 'parent', 'parentGenerator', 'parents', 'parserClass', 'parser_class', 'prefix', 'preserve_whitespace_tags', 'prettify', 'previous', 'previousGenerator', 'previousSibling', 'previousSiblingGenerator', 'previous_element', 'previous_elements', 'previous_sibling', 'previous_siblings', 'recursiveChildGenerator', 'renderContents', 'replaceWith', 'replaceWithChildren', 'replace_with', 'replace_with_children', 'select', 'select_one', 'setup', 'smooth', 'sourceline', 'sourcepos', 'string', 'strings', 'stripped_strings', 'text', 'unwrap', 'wrap']
```

But I can't do `.find('li')` operation successfully inside the else part. `c2` is always `NoneType`.

I have also tried these :

```
c2 = subheading.a
```

But it is also `NoneType`.

I've tried to do

```
c2 = subheading.find_all("li")
```

but then `c2` is a vacant list.

My end goal is to first check if the `li` tag exists and then find `a` tag and if it exists, access the `href` link and `text` of the `<a>` tag.

**NOTE** : I have tried to recreate the same thing in terminal which gave the correct `li` tag. I have tried keeping `subheading` in a string `h` and then doing `bs(h, 'html.parser')` on which `.find('li')` works but while running the script it gives me NoneType. **However the types of these two objects are different.** The script one is `<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>` but the one recreated in terminal is `<class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'>`. Does the different object type somehow opposes the attribute access or something similar?

Why are `.find('li')` or other processes giving me nonetype or failing even though the tag exists? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does `print([subheading.name])` output? And `print(subheading.find_all('a'))`? And `print(subheading.prettify())`? If the first gives you "li", then we know why `find('li')` returned empty, but `subheading.a` being NoneType is pretty baffling

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to clarify your code some, because I am getting different information than you.

`pip3 install bs4`

Then:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = """<li><a href="/handbook/PRIN/1/1.html?date=2022-10-14&amp;timeline=True">PRIN 1.1 Application and purpose</a></li>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
soup.find("li")
# Returns the Correct LI.
```

If this doesnt solve your issue, you may have a problem with what you are actually attempting to find.   Take another look at your string to confirm it is correct.

Documentation for BeautifulSoup is located at: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/ and will likely help you with ingesting the correct data format for querying.

Comment: Yep, this is strange because I also recreated the same thing in terminal which gave the correct `li` tag but while running the script it gives me NoneType. 

will add this info in the question.

Comment: If it works in a terminal but not in your script then it means your certainly doing something incorrect.   Can you please post most about your script, or how the subheading is populated ( even with the small sample code ) would help as well

Comment: I've just added some related info regarding this in the question as a note. One thing to note is that the object types are different if you recreate it by parsing from a string. Does it have to do anything with the attribute access?

Comment: Well, how do you create it, so i can take a look?  It needs to be an Accepted format.  If you can give me an example, i can take a look.   Are you passing in a filepointer, using `with open("foo.html") as fp:` or some other mechanism?  Part of me is thinking it is returning None now because it doesnt understand what you passed in to it.

Comment: no filepointer isn't involved. i have a baseurl `'https://www.handbook.fca.org.uk'` which i'm parsing with bs4 and doing `.find_all()` on the request text soup. Inside an iteration of all the elements found by `.find_all()`, i've this code. 

anyway, i found a solution to avoid the nonetype problem and get the wanted `li` tag inside. i couldn't figure out why it gives nonetype though btw. thanks for the help.

Comment: @ArkistarvhKltzuonstev I see that you put your answer down.   I am curious, what is the type of the `subheading` property?  There might be a better way to do it instead of stringify and then reparse it again.   There might be a formatter or something which accepts that type.  It says in your question it is already a BS4 Tag, but part of me is curious how it was set as such.

Answer (score 0):

I found a comical way to bypass the nonetype error I was facing. As `subheading` variable of type `bs4.element.Tag` and on the other hand `bs4.BeautifulSoup` type object was giving the correct `li` tags, I thought of type-casting `subheading` into string and then again parsing it with beautifulsoup so that its type gets changed to `bs4.BeautifulSoup` and then doing `.find('li')` works perfectly.

I changed my code to :

```
subheading_str = str(subheading)
subheading_soup = bs(subheading_str, "html.parser")
if subheading_soup.find("ul"):
    print(f"Going for next level subheading search")
else:
    c2 = subheading.find("li")
    print(f"c2 : {c2}") # Not nonetype this time, gives correct result
    if c2:
       # next code part
```

**NOTE** - This might not be right/technically correct way to solve the issue but does the work for me.